# No disparity from connected and synced stereo images (stereo_image_proc)

Tags: stereo, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm running some sensors on a system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo.
I use two Prosilica 1350 in a stereo setup with a resolution of 1360x1024. The cameras are calibrated with cameracalibrator.py and the .yaml-files are placed in ~/.ros/camera_info They are synced by hardware and I've checked the timing in `rqt` and they are within three microseconds (3 us). I use a launchfile with the relevant content showed below.

Problem: I do not get any disparity from the `stereo_image_proc`.
Question: What do I need to change in my launchfile to get the disparity?

I have tried everything on the "Possible issue"-list:

```
Possible issues:
        * stereo_image_proc is not running.     // Yes, its running ! 
          Does `rosnode info /stereo_cam` show any connections?   // It shows connections
        * The cameras are not synchronized.   // By Hardware
          Try restarting stereo_view with parameter _approximate_sync:=True     // Done 
        * The network is too slow. One or more images are dropped from each triplet.   
          Try restarting stereo_view, increasing parameter 'queue_size' (currently 50)     
          // Tried queue_size from 5 to 500 and even resized images
```

Sorry, I'm not able to upload any image of rosgraph, but the nodes seem connected.
I get the following warning:

```
[ WARN] [1469637939.617985018]: [stereo_view] Low number of synchronized left/right/disparity triplets received.
Left images received:      493 (topic '/stereo/left/image_rect')
Right images received:     492 (topic '/stereo/right/image_rect')
Disparity images received: 0 (topic '/stereo/disparity')
Synchronized triplets: 0
```

`rostopic echo /stereo/left/image_rect` and `rostopic echo /stereo/right/image_rect` show running data.

`rosnode info /stereo_cam` shows:

```
 Node [/stereo_cam]
    Publications: 
     * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /stereo/left/image_rect_color [sensor_msgs/Image]
 * /stereo/disparity [stereo_msgs/DisparityImage]
 * /stereo/right/image_rect_color [sensor_msgs/Image]

Services: 
 * /stereo_cam/set_logger_level
 * /stereo_cam/get_loggers

contacting node http://sas2-truck:33253/ ...
Pid: 13170
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /stereo/left/image_rect_color
    * to: /stereo/stereo_image_proc (http://sas2-truck:35006/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /stereo/right/image_rect_color
    * to: /stereo/stereo_image_proc (http://sas2-truck:35006/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /stereo/disparity
    * to: /stereo/stereo_image_proc (http://sas2-truck:35006/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Launchfile:

```
  <!-- Group with namespace, i.e. stereo -->
<group ns="stereo">  

  <!-- Left camera node --> 
  <node name="left" pkg="prosilica_camera" type="prosilica_node" output="screen"  >
     <param name="guid" type="str" value="$(arg guid)" />
    <param name="ip_address" type="str" value="192.168.101.2" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="left_optical_frame" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="cam_settings_1350_Kollmorgen.yaml" />
   <remap from="image_raw" to="/stereo/left/image_raw" />
   <remap from="camera_info" to="/stereo/left/camera_info" /> 
 </node>

  <!-- Right camera node -->
  <node name="right" pkg="prosilica_camera" type="prosilica_node" output="screen"  >
     <param name="guid" type="str" value="$(arg guid)" />
    <param name="ip_address" type="str" value="192.168.102.2" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="right_optical_frame" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="cam_settings_1350_Kollmorgen.yaml" /> 
   <remap from="image_raw" to="/stereo/right/image_raw" />
   <remap from="camera_info" to="/stereo/right/camera_info" /> 
 </node> 

<node name="stereo_image_proc" pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" output="screen" > 
<param name="approximate_sync" value="0.01" />
</node>
</group> 

<node name="stereo_cam" pkg="image_view" type="stereo_view" output="screen" >
<param name="queue_size" value="50" />
<param name="approximate_sync" value="True" />
<remap from="stereo/left/image" to="/stereo/left/image_rect" />
<remap from="stereo/right/image" to="/stereo/right/image_rect" />
</node>
```

Alternative:
I have also tried to downsample the images before `stereo_image_proc` with the same result.
launchfile:

```
 <!-- Group with namespace, i.e. stereo -->
<group ns="stereo">  
    
  <!-- Left camera node --> 
  <node name="left" pkg="prosilica_camera" type="prosilica_node" output="screen"  >
     <param name="guid" type="str" value="$(arg guid)" />
    <param name="ip_address" type="str" value="192.168.101.2" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="left_optical_frame" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="cam_settings_1350_Kollmorgen.yaml" />
   <remap from="image_raw" to="/left/image_raw" />
   <remap from="camera_info" to="/left/camera_info" /> 
 </node>
    
<!-- Resize left image -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
        args="standalone image_proc/crop_decimate"
        name="left_decimator">
    <param name="decimation_x" type="int" value="2" />
    <param name="decimation_y" type="int" value="2" />

    <!-- remap input topics -->
    <remap from="camera/image_raw" to="/left/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="camera/image_info" to="/left/camera_info"/>

    <!-- remap output topics -->
    <remap from="camera_out/image_raw" to="/stereo/left/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="camera_out/image_info" to="/stereo/left/camera_info"/>
</node>
    
  <!-- Right camera node -->
  <node name="right" pkg="prosilica_camera" type="prosilica_node" output="screen"  >
     <param name="guid" type="str" value="$(arg guid)" />
    <param name="ip_address" type="str" value="192.168.102.2" />
    <param name="frame_id" value="right_optical_frame" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="cam_settings_1350_Kollmorgen.yaml" /> 
   <remap from="image_raw" to="/right/image_raw" />

 </node> 
   
<!-- Resize right image -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
        args="standalone image_proc/crop_decimate"
        name="right_decimator">
    <param name="decimation_x" type="int" value="2" />
    <param name="decimation_y" type="int" value="2" />

    <!-- remap input topics -->
    <remap from="camera/image_raw" to="/right/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="camera/image_info" to="/right/camera_info"/>

    <!-- remap output topics -->
    <remap from="camera_out/image_raw" to="/stereo/right/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="camera_out/image_info" to="/stereo/right/camera_info"/>
</node>
    
<node name="stereo_image_proc" pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" output="screen" > 
<param name="approximate_sync" value="0.05" />
</node>

</group> 

<node name="stereo_cam" pkg="image_view" type="stereo_view" output="screen" >
<param name="queue_size" value="500" />
<param name="approximate_sync" value="True" />
<remap from="stereo/left/image" to="/stereo/left/image_rect_color" />
<remap from="stereo/right/image" to="/stereo/right/image_rect_color" />
</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240507/no-disparity-from-connected-and-synced-stereo-images-(stereo_image_proc)/) by [perfectspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/27103/perfectspeed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

you are mixing namespaces... remove the remappings at the end of your launchfile, and in the cameras publish to /left/image_raw and /right/image_raw (without the "/stereo"!) because you grouped everything inside a namespace.

Right now, cameras are publishing at /stereo/stereo/left_or_right/image_raw and stereo_image_proc expects them to be at /stereo/left_or_right/image_raw...

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [perfectspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/27103/perfectspeed/) on 2016-08-28**:
Thanks for your answer, Miquel. I changed the launch file to the one shown in my answer. I do not get any better result, even though the code is more correct.